# Stacking 3 divs and 4 images vertically on smaller screens

Tags: html, css

I am building a website and I'm on a time crunch, struggling to get the layout below to align vertically on smaller screen devices using media queries.

[image]

Desired vertical layout in this order for smaller screens:

1. intro
2. image 1
3. sidedoc
4. image 3
5. conclude
6. image 4

*image 2 not to be displayed on smaller screens*

```css
    .container {
 border-width: thick;
 border-style: groove;
 border-radius:5px;
 width:100%;
  }
  
.intro {width: 910px; text-align: justify; padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;}
 
.sidedoc { width: 390px; text-align: justify; float: right; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: -450px;}

.conclude {width: 920px; padding: 10px; text-align: justify; margin-top: 20px; }

.readysetgo {
    float: right;
 border-radius: 7px;
 margin-right: 28px;
 margin-top: -148px;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 10s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymove 10s infinite;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    50% {box-shadow: 10px 20px 30px green;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
    50% {box-shadow: 10px 20px 30px green;}
}


.reclaim {max-width: 100%;margin-left: 120px;}

 
.rounded {max-width: 50%; border-radius: 10px; float: right; margin-right: 17px; margin-top: -375px;}

   
.thinkgreen {max-width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; margin-bottom: 25px; margin-top: 20px;}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
  
  <div class="intro">
content 1
  </div>

<img src="Images/Capturegreen.JPG" width="375" height="191" alt="" class="readysetgo"/>

<img src="Images/TotalReclaimICON_NoShadow.jpg"  alt="" class="reclaim"/>


 <div class="sidedoc">
 content 2 
 </div>

<div class="conclude">
content 3
</div>

<img src="Images/ttr.jpg" width="375" height="370" alt="" class="rounded"/>

<img src="Images/thinkgreen.jpg" width="268" height="273" alt="" class="thinkgreen"/>

</div>
```

Comment: what's your code so far?

Comment: johannes, my codes are really long, but so far they have produced the results seen in the photo attached. See, enter image description here

Comment: It's not how it works. Anyway: [fiddle with `flex`](https://jsfiddle.net/dopaue68/), [fiddle with `float`](https://jsfiddle.net/53m9rgyb/). With some work you can adapt them and improve, but next time post MCVE or anything...

Comment: @green sorry, as i stated, i'm new to coding and also the site. I've included a snippet of my codes. I hope this can now help

Answer (score 0):

Here this is a basic layout for you https://jsfiddle.net/snpsp6as/5/

HTML

```
<div class="intro">
  intro
</div>
<img class="image1" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
<img class="image2" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
<div class="sidedoc">
  Side Doc
</div>
<img class="image3" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
<div class="conclude">
  conclude
</div>
<img class="image4" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div,
img {
  width: calc(50% - 6px);
  height: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
  float: left;
}

.image3 {
  float: right
}

.image4 {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  float: none;
}

img {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  //width: 400px;
  //height: 100px;
}

@media(max-width: 800px) {
  div,
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .image2 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

**EXPAND THE WINDOW** see image below 
[image]

Comment: Adam, everything is already vertically aligned in your fiddle. My layout has to be exactly as seen in the photo, http://i.stack.imgur.com/M89Xo.png, and then vertically align itself as the screen gets smaller on devices.

Comment: @cyberhood make the window bigger and it will not be vertically algined

Comment: @cyberhood look at the attached image

Comment: i see it now. sorry about that! i'm going to give it a go!

Comment: i'm not achieving those results. i edited my message and inserted my actual codes above, can you have a look at that?

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways you can achieve this, one way is with `@media` in your css.

Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/Cheesetoast/pen/KFAaq) using `@media`

HTML

```
<div id="pagewrap">

    <header>
        <h1>3 Column Responsive Layout</h1>
    </header>

    <section id="content">
        <h2>1st Content Area</h2>
        <p>This page demonstrates a 3 column responsive layout, complete with responsive images and jquery slideshow.</p>
    </section>

    <section id="middle">
        <h2>2nd Content Area</h2>
        <p>At full width all three columns will be displayed side by side. As the page is resized the third column will collapse under the first and second. At the smallest screen size all three columns will be stacked on top of one another.</p>
        <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
    </section>

    <aside id="sidebar">
        <h2>3rd Content Area</h2>
        <p>Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
        <p>Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
    </aside>

    <footer>
        <h4>Footer</h4>
        <p>Footer text</p>
    </footer>

</div>
```

CSS

```
/* STRUCTURE */

#pagewrap {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
header {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
#content {
    width: 290px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

#middle {
    width: 294px; /* Account for margins + border values */
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 270px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    float: left;
}
footer {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

/***********************MEDIA QUERIES***********/
/* for 980px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {

    #pagewrap {
        width: 94%;
    }
    #content {
        width: 41%;
        padding: 1% 4%;
    }
    #middle {
        width: 41%;
        padding: 1% 4%;
        margin: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
        float: right;
    }

    #sidebar {
        clear: both;
        padding: 1% 4%;
        width: auto;
        float: none;
    }

    header, footer {
        padding: 1% 4%;
    }
}

/* for 700px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    #content {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
    }

    #middle {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }

    #sidebar {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
    }

}

/* for 480px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    header {
        height: auto;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    #sidebar {
        display: none;
    }

}

#content {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
#sidebar {
    background: #f0efef;
}
header, #content, #middle, #sidebar {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#pagewrap, header, #content, #middle, #sidebar, footer {
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

Again credit to [this page](https://codepen.io/Cheesetoast/pen/KFAaq)

Comment: i dont understand the answer you gave :( i'm sorry but i'm new to coding. my current layout is as seen here, http://i.stack.imgur.com/M89Xo.png ... and i would like to achieve a vertical layout as the screen gets smaller on devices... but in this vertical order: (1)intro (2)image 1 (3)sidedoc (4)image 3 (5)conclude (6)image 4

image 2 not to be displayed on smaller screens

Comment: not quite sure how I got down vote for this, it does answer the question. anyways... @cyberhood if you clicked the link you would see an example of this and all you have to do is put your content that is going to be on the left in the "1st content" area and so on down the line. That will be the order it also stacks when the screen shrinks

Comment: i edited my message above and inserted my actual codes. Yours doesnt include the image

Comment: @cyberhood yea your code does not make sense for what you are trying to do, what I am showing you is how you should be doing it.  here is a demo https://jsfiddle.net/q32u1m18/

Comment: the divs are doing what it's suppose to, but how do i get the images to do the same?